# A clever alternative in LINQ for iterating over HashSet<string>

Tags: c#, linq, hashset

I've got a whitelist of URLs I'm using, inside a `HashSet<string>`. I'm trying to find if the `url` starts with any of the items in the white list (it has to be that way round).

*Edit:* The previous example was a bit misleading and had a typo - I already have a base url like yahoo.com, the whitelist is just the path.

```
HashSet<string> whiteList = new HashSet<string>();

string path = "/sport/baseball/";
bool validUrl = false;

foreach (string item in whiteList)
{
    if (path.StartsWith(item))
    {
        validUrl = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this lookup with LINQ (to objects)? The list isn't huge so performance isn't an issue.

Comment: btw, the `HashSet<T>` isn't helping you here; this only helps with equality tests. If you don't use the `HashSet<T>` in some other way, replace it with a `List<T>` - it'll be faster to build (assuming you don't have vast numbers of duplicates).

Comment: Marc: Presumably he's using `HashSet` so he doesn't get duplicate links.

Comment: @silky - hence my "assuming", but you normally have control of a white-list, so this shouldn't be a huge risk.

Comment: As the url path is always unique I thought it made sense to have it as a set not a list

Comment: If the list is small and performance is good, then stick with the HashSet. If the list becomes large, you could improve asymptotic performance by using a sorted list instead of a hash set. A sorted list is more expensive to build, but much faster to search; you can binary-search the list for the closest match to the path and then check just that one to see if it is an exact prefix match.

Comment: Oh, and speaking of which, I hear there will be a SortedSet type in the next version of the framework base class library.

Comment: Finally on par with Java's collections! The only part of Java I thought was stronger than .NET/C#

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
bool validUrl = whiteList.Any(item => linkUrl.StartsWith(item));
```

By the way, in general, hash tables are not good data structures for these kind of problems (where you don't have the key and are matching the key based on a function) as you'll have to enumerate the whole table all the time. You can use a simple `List<string>` to hold the items instead and you'll get better performance.

Comment: @Spence: Functional programming is a cave of wonders. Wonders are going to be rediscovered as time goes on.

Comment: It's not quite there yet in C# because the compiler in the general case still writes imperative code.  It will be very interesting if the C# compiler can start doing fancy stuff based on the fact that your asking the computer to perform a given function, not HOW to perform it.

Comment: Spence: That makes no sense at all.

Comment: I'm guessing `Any` is faster than the overhead of a hashtable, though the whitelist is actually just read once from a file path in the constructor

Comment: @Chris S: `Any` is basically a `foreach` loop and should be similar to what you've written performance-wise. Nevertheless, the same code is applicable for `List<string>` as `Any` works on *any* object that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. I don't think it makes a meaningful difference for your case as the white list is probably small.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with the lookup.  Do you have any regularity in the whitelist?  i.e will it always be a domain you're after, not neccessarily the pages within or a specific subdomain?

If so you could use a string.split to grab the first URL part from your string, then use the .Contains() method of your hashset to get the item.  This would remove the string.StartsWith() command which is run once for every element in the list, and an expensive string compare, and replace it with a one off string.split and a O(1) lookup of your hashset.

```
HashSet<string> whiteList = new HashSet<string>();
//add items

string urlStartsWith = "http://www.yahoo.com";
bool validURL = whiteList.Contains(url);
```